# Problem with attaching a process in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, vb6, process

I am not sure what the issue is as I am new to this issue, but I'll describe the problem best I can. I have reportwriter dll written in VB6. I use this reportwriter in a web app (my main app).

At the moment, I am building the reportwriter project into a dll into the a folder in my main app's solution. I have been told VB6 automatically registers the dll when i build it. I then reference the reportwriter dll in a main app's solution.

I then start debugging in the reportwriter project in VB6, then start debugging in my main app. I attach the VB6 reportwriter process. I then place a break point in the reportwriter project, and try to step into it from the main app, but it does not recognise it. It just goes over it.

I got to say that I am running all this on 64bit machine and 64bit version of Vista. Not sure if that has any impact on it.

Any ideas? I know its a bit of a weird question. Any help would be great, as I am stuck. Cheers.

Comment: The content here is a little confusing.  You've built a Report writer __dll__ so where does the "report writer process" come from?? Why are you not debugging this with the VB6 IDE? "Web app" thats ASP Classic right?

Comment: Sorry if its confusing. I am debugging the reportwriter in the VB6 IDE. Then I start debugging the web application in the VS2008 IDE. The web application I refere to is an amalgamation of various projects (WCF, Class libraries and a MVC project).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the appropriate options selected before you attach to the process?  For example, managed and unmanaged code?

-Shaun

Comment: I am not sure what you mean managed/unmanaged code options. I believe this is unmanaged code. Other than that, I dont know any of options to select. Where are the options you are referring to ?

Comment: I don't see an answer here, should've been a comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes VB6 will register the dll it builds.

Now when you start debugging a VB6 project in the VB6 IDE the registry is modified to point at the host process.  Your component becomes an out-of-process component for the duration of the debug.

I've never done it with VS 2008 but in the past you could build a dll with options to emit the a symbols file (.pdb) and debug the component using Visual Studio using native code debugging.

For that to have any chance to work you would need to attach to the web app (I'm assuming ASP classic here) for native code debugging.